# I can't access my Watson Studio via Get Started - gets Authorize Redirect ratelimit

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I have tried to log out and log in. Deleted the service and created a new one. No success thou. When I look at the url I see I'm being thrown around the entire planet...

Comment: This seems like a support question, but you didn't provide much details.

Comment: What more is needed? I can't access Watson Studio service. When I click Get Started I get AUTHORIZE REDIRECT RATELIMIT

Answer (score 0):

Try and log into Watson Studio directly at: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/settings/regions?context=cpdaas and then select the region where you have provision the Watson Studio instance in IBM Cloud.

Please note that the Watson Studio instance in IBM Cloud is used for entitlement checking and billing. Deleting this instance via IBM Cloud does not remove your Watson Studio projects etc.